# Azure IoT Central - Get "Device ID" by "Device Connection ID"

Tags: power-automate, azure-iot-central

I have a real Use Cace with Azure IoT Central:

1. Device manufactured, serial number printed on the device case:

   - S/N = "08-00-27-04-77-77"
2. Device registered in IoT Central:

   - Device ID = S/N (08-00-27-04-77-77)
3. User runs MS Flow:

   - Manually trigger a flow:

     - set device S/N (08-00-27-04-77-77)
     - set license key (string)
   - Run Action: IoT Central - Update a device

So, I have a problem: I need a **Device ID** to run "Update a device" action, but I don't know it. IoT Central Device have a two IDs:

1. Device Connection ID - value defined on device registration (08-00-27-04-77-77) - Ok, you can find it on Device Page ("Connect" button, "Device ID" field)
2. Device ID - generated by IoT Central (q1aa9u) - How to get it? you can find it in Device Page URL only.

IoT Central:
[image: IoT Central IDs]

MS Flow Action:
[image: MS Flow Action]

Questions:

- How to run MS Flow action "Iot Central - Update a device" using
  Device Connection ID ?
- or How to get Device ID by Device Connection ID using MS Flow action or API?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new device in MS Flow then you can get the device ID in the response (via dynamic content).

Otherwise, there is no way to get the device ID via the device connection ID.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new MS Flow action "Find Device" ? For some business processes, I need to find the Device in IoT Central by the Property value.
For example:
1. I know the Name of the device, but I do not know the ID
2. I find this device in Central, get the ID
3. Using the ID, I can perform an action on the Device (update, delete, run the command).
Iot Central already implemented search, there is a need to add such an action to the MS Flow